# Prevent query assigning ID when column has a default

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table that has a column defined as `id serial`. Therefore, it has a default on the column to call a sequencer. Which is what I want. However, my boss (and owner of the company) insists on having full access to the database and likes to write his own queries (including inserts) on this table. And even more unfortunately, he seems to always forgets that these IDs should be auto-generated for him, and he creates the record with max(id) + 1. Then the sequencer is out of sync with the table and the next time someone calls the API we get a 500.

Question: Given that I don't have the ability to lock him out of the database, what is the best way to prevent him from doing this?

My first idea was create a before insert trigger and raise an error if the ID was assigned. Here is what I did:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION md.tf_no_manual_keys()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE

BEGIN

    IF NEW.id IS NOT NULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'ID must be assigned from sequencer';
    END IF;

END;
$function$

trigger_no_manual_keys BEFORE INSERT ON vendor FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tf_no_manual_keys()
```

But, this doesn't work because the sequencer has already fired (I didn't think that was the case for a "BEFORE" trigger).

I guess I could always call the trigger on BEFORE INSERT, but that seems like it would use 2 IDs whenever it's called.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: Define the column as a "regular" integer column and the assign the value unconditionally in the trigger based on the sequence, overwriting whatever any user supplies as a value. You should also teach your boss, that using `max(id)+1` to "generate" an ID is stupid and doesn't work in a system where more than one user works on the database. (Btw: it's not called a "sequencer", it's just a "sequence")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [`grant`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) privilege on the table you can [`revoke`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html) a role's `insert` privilege on a certain column:

```
revoke insert (id) on table t from role_name;
```

But that will not work if that role is a member of another role that has that privilege.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, he owns the company and wants insert. I can't revoke the privileges (unless I want to find another job).

Comment: @DavidS He will still be able to insert but will not be able to set a value for that column in an insert.